# Potential-based reward shaping in DQN reinforcement learning

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I work for quite some time on a RL task which poses a surprising difficulty to the reinforcement learning agent to learn.

My technique is based on the Double DQN, with replay buffer, using recurrent NNs to evaluate Q, with e-greedy action selection (0.1 probability for taking a random action).

The most difficulty goes from the fact that the agent has to make quite a series of right actions in order to stumble upon a positive sparse reward. The number of actions it should make is just about 5 (and the action vocabulary contains just 3 actions), but it should make them in a specific environmental state, which also complicates things.

As a result, replay buffer can have zero positive rewards per 1024 visited states (very sparse).

I tried to shape intermediate rewards based on potential function, in order to inject some positive traits into the buffer.

**My question is rather about intuition. Could you say the agent got stuck in a suboptimal policy?**

[image]

From left to right:

- Q values of selected actions
- L2 loss
- average reward at the end of a trajectory.

Although the Q values and (not shown here) the moving sum of rewards stay positive, the final rewards as trajectory ends cannot break through the zero level **(right pic)**. Anything above the zero level is a good result, and if it is above 1, the result is fantastically perfect.

My quess has been that the agent had found a 'loophole' for keeping the sum of intermediate and final rewards at maximum, while **the** final rewards are in fact negative.